# CSS hover - can it effect multiple divs with same class name

Tags: html, css

I have 5 div's all with the same class name like this:

CSS:

```
.test:hover{
   color:red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
```

Imagine for a moment these Div's are in different parent div's on the page...

I'm trying to find a way so they all change to `color:red` if i hover my mouse over any of the 5 rather than just the one in question changing...

I can't wrap them in a parent and give that parent a hover how ever... they are not sharing the same parents in the first place.

Does CSS provide a way to do this or am I going to have to rest to JavaScript?

Comment: When you hover on an element, the state is applied only to that element even if other elements have the same CSS rules. Using JavaScript is the only way to achieve what you want.

Comment: I know you said you can't wrap them.. but http://jsfiddle.net/J9GP3/

Comment: @joshC yeh thats not guna work for my situation! Looks like Javacsript is the only way.

Comment: Pretty sure you would have to use JS for this though. There aren't any selectors that would achieve this.. `~`, `+`, `>` wouldn't work..

Comment: You will have to use JavaScript, because CSS only allows you to go down the DOM tree, and not up (i.e. selecting parents, or parents' siblings and the likes).

Comment: What about using the not selector...  http://kilianvalkhof.com/2008/css-xhtml/the-css3-not-selector/

Comment: @w3bMak3r How should that work?

Comment: @w3bMak3r what do you mean ?

Comment: Let me create a fiddle to illustrate... brb

Comment: @w3bMak3r I would be very surprised if your (pure CSS) fiddle worked, really.

Comment: Do u want this .. http://jsfiddle.net/UeRzd/?

Comment: Yeah it did not work.  Sorry

Comment: @DOCTYPEHTML no they do not share a parent i mentioned that in the question.

Comment: I no jsfiddle and no answer is good (!?!), the problem is with the question: please complement the question or add a complete code to show what you want.

Comment: @PeterKrauss it's not difficult to understand at all everyone else understands the point i'm asking.

Comment: Years later, does anyone know if there is a way to do this without javascript yet? I've come across the same issue and having to resort to using javascript only right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One (plain/vanilla) JavaScript approach that works (in compliant browsers, which support `[].forEach()`, and `document.querySelectorAll()`), given that CSS *cannot* (yet) perform this task, is:

```
function classToggle (evt, find, toggle) {
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.' + find), function(a){
        a.classList[evt.type === 'mouseover' ? 'add' : 'remove'](toggle);
    });
}

var els = document.querySelectorAll('.test');

for (var i = 0, len = els.length; i<len; i++){
    els[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(e){
        classToggle(e, 'test', 'highlight');
    });
    els[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function(e){
        classToggle(e, 'test', 'highlight');
    });
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4eQUm/).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll).
- [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList).
- [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Comment: Thanks for the non jQuery option :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use JQuery to pretty easily achieve what you want... copy this to an .html file to test it...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".test").hover(
              function() {
                $(".test").css("background-color", "red");
              }, function() {
                $(".test").css("background-color", "");
              }
            );
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="test">My Div</div><br />
        <div class="test">My Div</div><br />
        <div class="test">My Div</div><br />
        <div class="test">My Div</div><br />
        <div class="test">My Div</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: in your fiddle, in left corner, select one of jquery libraries, for example jQuery 1.9.1...it will work then

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

**css**:

```
.sample{
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
height: 105px;
opacity: 0.1;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 5%;
}
.sample:hover ~ div{
color:red;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

**html**:

```
<div class="sample"></div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="test">1111</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="test">2222</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="test">3333</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="test">4444</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="test">5555</div>
</div>
```

Check the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/eN49z/

Comment: It fails entirely when they're in separate containers and only affects later-siblings, not *all* siblings. CSS really cannot do what this question requires. Also: why have you introduced a new element to target the `:hover`?

Comment: @David thomas I agree with your point.Well this is the max i could do using css...:)

Comment: Yeah, I know; that's pretty much why I've not down-voted, because this really *is* the closest you can get (without a parent-selector) to what the question is asking.

Comment: @david thomas i tried with parent selector.Check my updated code.

Comment: @Joke_Sense10, I don't think there is a way to make it work with a complex real markup, check example http://jsfiddle.net/eN49z/4/

Comment: @sheriffderek Not upto the mark though..Well this all i could do only using css..:)

Comment: CSS still has secret stuff nobody thinks of, so you always have to push it and see if you can find a trick someone hasn't found. They are there! People didn't ever think to use @media rules for anything like they do now for example.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to select element's parent via CSS nowadays. So also it's impossible to select element by one element and general parent. It's like a tiny proof.

Comment: @sheriffderek I meant rather "yet", not "already" =) With hope that CSS4 give us more opportunities.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer: it is not possible via CSS-only to achieve the effect that you are looking for, as CSS is unable to travel up the parent, but only down the DOM tree to affect elements.

You can, however, rely on JavaScript to achieve the effect. In my example I have chosen to rely on jQuery. You can use various methods to get all other `<div>`s with the class `test`, but it depends on how they are nested - are they nested under parents that are siblings, and the level of nesting and etc.

Here is an example markup of the scenario you have described:

```
<div>
    Parent 1
    <div class="test"></div>
</div>
<div>
    Parent 2
    <div class="test"></div>
</div>
<div>
    Parent 3
    <div class="test"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS would be simple. The `.hover` class (not the `:hover` state) is added dynamically by jQuery (see below):

```
.test:hover, .test.hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

The JS would be something like:

```
$(function() {
    $(".test").hover(function() {
        // Find '.test' in all siblings of a specific '.test' parent
        $(this).parent().siblings().find(".test").addClass("hover");
    }, function() {
        // You can refine the criteria of which '.test' should be selected.
        $(document).find(".test").removeClass("hover");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/fHwFf/