# Same Class Name for div but hover only one at a time

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have 5 `div` s with same class names called tile and I generate these `div`s dynamically. I am working on ASP.NET MVC project and based on the models I generate the tiles.

I have added the hover method for these tiles from this example using jQuery https://stackoverflow.com/a/19480774

My requirement is that, only the hovered tile need to trigger the jQuery function so that particular tile's content change. As of now all the tiles content change when I hover any one tile div. 
I guess it is because all the div have same class and I am adding hover event based on the class name. Is there a small tweak in jQuery like stop propagation or should I have use id's for each div like tile-1 for each div and in some way have selectors in jQuery to add hove event?

As requested, My code is (Made changes according to answers)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var wapper;
    $(".tile").hover(function (e) { //mouse in
         // previously had wapper = (".tile-contents-wrapper");
        wapper = $(this).find(".tile-contents-wrapper");
            wapper.find("div:first-child").hide();
            wapper.find("div:last-child").show();
        },
        function (e) { //mouse out
            wapper.find("div:first-child").show();
            wapper.find("div:last-child").hide();
        });

});
```

I guess it is not possible using CSS and its my mistake not to mention that I am looking for an answer using jQuery and not with CSS.

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: When you post your code and we make the change your mind will be blown!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are telling all the members of the class to change color or text. Simply change the inner part to just "this" - the hovered element

```
$( ".mytile" ).hover(
    function() {
        $( this ).text(  "Hover" );
    }, function() {
        $( this ).text( "No hover");
    }
 );
```

The [JQuery hover documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) has a similar example and more information

Answer (score 2):

You don't need jQuery to do this, just plain ol' CSS will do what you want:

```
.test:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

[View the example](http://jsfiddle.net/DYxgD/)

Comment: @BigChris - Ah, you're correct.  There wasn't any code posted with the question and the other question that was linked dealt with changing styles (I presumed he was the author of the other question, but it looks like he wasn't).

Answer (score 0):

You need to target your classes but use "$(this)" so that an individual element of your class is changed:

```
$('.group1').hover(
    function() { 
        $(this).addClass('tbl_navGroupHover'); }, 
    function() { 
        $(this).removeClass('tbl_navGroupHover'); 
});
```

if you need to change any content within your tiles you'll probably want to look at jQuery functions like `.html()` allowing you to dynamically change the inner content of one of your tiles.

The CSS answer above will work for your styling and is useful. You may have some existing classes, however, that you want to apply and remove. The CSS only approach will work but can lead to additional or duplicate styles.

Comment: Cheers Jay. I'm on mobile and I don't know how to do a block like that! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same code from the link you provided, adding a hover selector to it will solve your issue.

```
$(".tile ").hover(
    function() {
        $(".tile:hover").css("background-color", "red");
    }, 
    function() {
        $(".tile ").css("background-color", "");
    }
);
```

In the example that you provided link for, hover in function selects all of the elements with test class. This results in highlighting of all the divs. But if you add the hover selector, you only select the div that is hovered at that moment.

Also other answers suggesting usage of pure CSS will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".row.signup-popup-row").hover(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
}, function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "");
});
```